# Java Swing GUI JLabel Not Showing

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel

I am trying to write a Title for the main menu of my program, by using a JLabel, but it doesn't seem to appear on my screen.

```
import javax.swing.*;


public class GUI {

    public GUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30,30,10,30));
            panel.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Title");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(854,560);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        JLabel title = new JLabel();
        title.setText("Title");
        //title.setSize();
        title.setVisible(true);



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUI();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how could I change the position of the Text if I manage to make it visible?

And I also want to add a button to go to the next page so if you could tell me how to do that too that would be great.

Comment: You need to add title to panel.

Comment: Oracle has a useful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html), that will teach you the correct way to construct a Swing GUI.  Skip the Netbeans section.

Answer (score 0):

I would quickly and untested say that you are adding the label after you set the frame visible.
Do it before. Else you would have to revalidate and repaint the frame

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in your code you are not adding `title` in `panel`. As a quick solution put `panel.add(title);` after `title.setVisible(true);` line in your code, it will display the label.

```
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30,30,10,30));
            panel.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Title");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(854,560);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        JLabel title = new JLabel();
        title.setText("Title");
        //title.setSize();
        title.setVisible(true);
        panel.add(title);  //<---- this one line will diaplay label in GUI
```